# My 'if statement' won't work

Tags: python, if-statement

```
def main():
    while True:
        operation = raw_input('Choose an operation: ')

        if operation == 1:
            number_1 = int(raw_input("What is the first number you want to subtract? "))
            number_2 = int(raw_input("What do you want to subtract from it? "))
            sum = number_1 - number_2
            print('The answer is...')
            print(sum)
            break

        if operation == 2:
            number_1 = int(raw_input("What is the first number you want to subtract? "))
            number_2 = int(raw_input("What do you want to subtract from it? "))
            sum = number_1 - number_2
            print('The answer is...')
            print(sum)
            break

        if operation == 3:
            number_1 = int(raw_input("What is the first number you want to subtract? "))
            number_2 = int(raw_input("What do you want to subtract from it? "))
            sum = number_1 - number_2
            print('The answer is...')
            print(sum)
            break

        if operation == 4:
            number_1 = int(raw_input("What is the first number you want to subtract? "))
            number_2 = int(raw_input("What do you want to subtract from it? "))
            sum = number_1 - number_2
            print('The answer is...')
            print(sum)
            break

        else:
            print('Invalid operation')
            break
main()
```

When I try to input a number it doesn't recognise it and prints Invalid operation

Comment: raw_input takes a string, input() takes a number

Comment: That is not true; in Python 2.x `input()` is equivalent to `eval(raw_input())`.

Answer (score 2):

You have to convert the input to an integer with [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

```
operation = int(raw_input('Choose an operation: '))
```

Answer (score 0):

set your if statements to something like:

```
if int(operation) == 1
```

or

```
if operation == str(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to compare strings:

`if operation == "1":`

Answer (score 0):

operation needs to be an int if you have it checking 
against a int for your if statements.

```
operation = raw_input('Choose an operation: ')
```

should be

```
operation = int(raw_input('Choose an operation: '))
```

As a side note, make sure you proofread your code before asking. :)